# How to reference to other glyphs in fontforge?

Tags: fontforge

Let's say we a have a glyph named "fi" so it is composed from "f" and "i" so how can I referenced that to substitute the f+i in the font with this glyph(i.e., "fi")? through scripting with fontforge or even if you have any idea how can I do that with the fontforge user interface, I will appreciate that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, you're question is "how can I create a glyph for one character (e.g., 'i') and then have a different character (e.g., 'fi') simply reference the glyph that I created for the other character?".

I was also having difficulty figuring out how to do this.  Eventually, I tried this; and it worked:

1. Open the character that you want to edit
2. In the list of characters, navigate to the character that has the glyph you want to reference
3. Single-click the character to select it
4. Now Click-and-drag from the list into the Edit window for the character you're editing

Comment: Thanks for your reply, as I was saying in my question. I am looking for a way to do that through scripting for fontforge

Answer (score 0):

There is a unicode point for that particular ligature, http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fb01/index.htm

OpenType Layout is used to create ligatures.

The FontForge UI for it is explained here: http://code.newtypography.co.uk/creating-contextual-ligatures-in-fontforge/